# FTPS server giving Error: Timeout (control socket)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftps, ftp-server

I am trying to connect to ftps server using node js. I am using "https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp" module. but its giving me following error. I have tried many modules but same error is occured. Please help me out

index.js

```
    const ftp = require("basic-ftp")

    example();

    async function example() {
     const client = new ftp.Client()
        client.ftp.verbose = true;
        try {
        const secureOptions = {
             rejectUnauthorized: false,
              host: "xxx.xxx.com",
              port:990

                };

         await client.access({
                host: "xxx.xxx.com",
                port:990,
                user: "xxxx@xxxx.xxx",
                secure:true, 
                password: "xxxxxx",
                secureOptions : secureOptions


            });

    }
    catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }


Error: Timeout (control socket)
    at Socket.socket.once (D:\node\basicftp\node_modules\basic-ftp\dist\FtpConte
xt.js:310:58)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Comment: use client.ftp.verbose=true to see where did it stuck. And add logs into your question

Comment: It's already true client.ftp.verbose = true;  I will paste my entire code

Comment: In my case I solved the problem using `ssh2-sftp-client` package. `FTPS` and `SFTP` is not the same thing!